# Biztalk logic into orchestration on transport level crash

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

I have orchestration like on screenshot below.
And I want to have additional logic executed when service connected to **wsp** is failing or unavailable (timeout,service crash,  server unavailable, etc).

It looks like I will not be able to catch this in orchestration  in **Scope_1**.

How can I add logic to orchestration if service crashed ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the pattern described in this article or some variation:

[BizTalk Server: Suspend and Resume an Orchestration on Two Way Port Error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31665.biztalk-server-suspend-and-resume-an-orchestration-on-two-way-port-error.aspx?Sort=MostRecent&PageIndex=1)

This pattern captures the Port error, and puts the Orchestration in a Suspended/Resumable state.

You should still properly configure the Port Retries.

Comment: Thank you for the link.I have question : In the article mentioned that "When a Port Exception occurs, it is caught buy the Catch Exception box. "  Why in my case exception didn't cached by Catch Exception box ?

Comment: @PomodoroTechniqueGame Did you check the sample?  Without seeing the project, my guess is the Port is missing the Fault Message.

Comment: You probably right, I don't see Fault on ports in example but I see "New Fault Message" on right -click , however I do not see "New Fault Message" on my port type. Is this because it's imported WCF port   ?